# How I can "update" a plot in Sympy?

Tags: python, plot, sympy

I'm trying to plot iterations of a function using sympy, but I can't make that in every iteration the plot refresh. How i can do that?. I appreciate your help.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = Symbol('x')
t = Symbol('t')

x_0 = exp(t)
ut = 1
mu = -1
ker = x-t

for i in range(1,20):
    x_0 = ut + mu * integrate(ker * x_0, (t, 0, x))
    print(i, x_0)
    p1 = plot(x_0, (x,-1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of two different plots taken from [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html) of `append` method of `sympy.plotting.plot.Plot` class:

```
p1 = plot(x*x, show=False)
p2 = plot(x, show=False)
p1.append(p2[0])
p1.show()
```

Notice that `p1` and `p2` are instances of `sympy.plotting.plot.Plot` class. `append` method adds an element from a plot’s series to an existing plot and finally a bunch of these elements can be shown calling `show` on this plot. I can adapt this example for your case now. Note that I create a `plot` instance that has no elements of plot series at the beginning:

```
p = plot(show=False)
for i in range(1,20):
    x_0 = ut + mu * integrate(ker * x_0, (t, 0, x))
    print(i, x_0)
    p.append(plot(x_0, (x,-1,1), show=False)[0])
p.show()
```